# Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' Server.CreateObject Failed

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm using Classic ASP.

```
Set theForm = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
theForm.OverwriteFiles = True
```

Running the above code produces the error:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' Server.CreateObject Failed
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try running an `regsvr32` on the Persits Upload DLL? Look at this: http://support.persits.com/show.asp?code=PS01032622

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unregister the Persits Upload DLL and re-register it by using regsvr32. below are the steps to register and unregister the DLL

**Registering a DLL**

```
regsvr32 <filename>.dll
```

or

```
regsvr32 <path>\<filename>.dll
```

where  is the path to the file, and  is the name of the file.

**Unregistering a DLL**

```
regsvr32 -u <filename>.dll
```

or

```
regsvr32 -u <path>\<filename>.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

In Classic ASP I was getting this error when the code was moved to a new server.  From my little experience with Classic ASP it looked like another DLL registration issue.  In my case was the DLL was missing, so it couldn't have been registered.  Once it was registered it fixed the problem.

Here is a list of items to check:

- You really didn't run regsvr32 on the server after all.
- You ran regsvr32 but it reported an error.
- Someone modified security on part of the registry that's preventing the OLE subsystem from reading all or part of the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT tree.
- The name of the object you are trying to create was mispelled or is incorrect.
- Determine if it's a permissions problem

Here are is a link for more information:

[Using the correct version of MSXML](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Comprehensive Check-list I posted here

[Error ASP 0177: 8007007e Server.CreateObject fails for COM DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942)

Deals with the issues of registering DLLs for use in Classic ASP for both 32 and 64 bit and common problems encountered.

Would post it here but don't want to duplicate the answer.