# Run Classic ASP without integrating with COM component

Tags: asp-classic, com

My ASP application uses the COM component but my client is not providing me the dll or the source code of the COM. I need to make the ASP site responsive using the bootstrap. Please suggest me that how I can run the application without integrating with the COM library.

Also I have the server path where they have deployed there existing site. When I run the site it runs properly. My question is that how that server path is interacting with the COM. I do not find any dll deployed there like usually it happens with ASP.Net or MVC.

Please suggest me.

Comment: The DLL will be registered on the server using `regsvr32.exe`, it is a manual process and DLLs I likely stored somewhere in the server file structure outside of the web application space. If you are trying to run a local copy of the site and the client won't let you have the DLL you will just have to comment out the `Server.Createobject"....") statements where the progid for the COM component is used.

Comment: If using any back end data a grid is populating, and I have to make that grid as the responsive design, then how I can make the change. As I have commented the Server.Create object so I can not see any grid on the page. Grid is visible only when there is any data coming from the back end.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what the COM component does, if it's just a data layer could you not mock the data instead and pass that to the grid for testing?

Comment: Yes. Mocking can be helpful here. Thanks, I will think for this one. Currently I am running the ASP application on VS 2015. Can I get the (COM) dll from anywhere so that I will use that in my solution. Can I get it from anywhere from the windows location or server path from the machine from where I can open the deployed site.

Comment: *"my client is not providing me the dll or the source code of the COM"* have you asked them for it? The thing is the only relationship to the DLL is through the progid *(the string you use in `Server.CreateObject()` to create the COM instance)* and that is located in the Windows Registry on the web server where the web application is running, if you can access the registry on the web server you can find the location of the DLL. [Here is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942) I give that explains where in the registry it's stored and how to locate the DLL.