# Finding DLL Dependencies for Classic ASP Web application

Tags: iis, dll, vbscript, asp-classic

I am a system admin tasked with migrating Classic ASP based web application from Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6) to Windows Server 2008 r2 (IIS 7.5)

The application is very old written in around 2002-03 and the concerned developer people are not around anymore to let me know anything related to this Web Application.

After lot of trial and error, I have been able to get the Web Application running on 2008 r2.

While navigating through application, I am getting various errors which on further investigation I understood are related to DLLs which the Web Application is invoking.

My issue is, I don't know what all DLLs are used/invoked on the source server, which I need to copy & register on the new server.

I tried to use DependancyWalker but I am not able to find a way to use this tool for Web Application.

I would really appreciate this community's help in this regard.

Comment: There's plenty of advice here how to identify COM dll dependancies. [Error ASP 0177: 8007007e Server.CreateObject fails for COM DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not rocket science.

When you find a COM component dependancy you can use the `ProgId` to identify and locate the DLL which is registered in the Windows Registry.

The only DLL dependancies come from COM component DLLs and these can only be invoke in Classic ASP / VBScipt with the

```
Server.CreateObject("ProgId")
```

and

```
CreateObject("ProgId")
```

respectively.

> Wrote about this extensively here
>
> [Error ASP 0177: 8007007e Server.CreateObject fails for COM DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942)

Comment: Thank you, this is surely going to help. As I am a non-coder techie I really didn't understand many other articles on the topic, but this one is really good. Thank you

Comment: @PankajBhalerao I'm glad you found it helpful. Welcome to [so].

Answer (score 2):

I found out a simple way of finding the DLLs which are specific to my Web Application.

I got a small freeware utility called as RegDLLView from Nirsoft.net which lists all the DLLs which are registered with the Server with File Paths, Description, Company name, etc details.

I found out all the DLLs which my Web Application is invoking by checking the company name and paths of all the DLLs which were listed.

Now I just have to copy these DLLs to my new server and register these on the new system.

Comment: I'm not sure listing every DLL is that useful, ideally you only want the COM dlls.