# Server.CreateObject Failed on IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, com, iis-8.5

I have moved one of the classic asp site from 6.0 to 8.5, while opening any page page it is giving below error

> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
>
> Server.CreateObject Failed
>
> /TestPlan/include/CommonFunctions.asp, line 4
>
> 800401f3

CommanFunctions.asp code is

```
Dim c_objState

Set c_objState = Server.CreateObject("ST_API.State")-- line 4

c_bag = c_objState.API_ViewStateBag(Request("ST"))-- line 5
```

Same application is working fine on IIS 6.0. Not getting what to do because I have provided full access permission to the folder then also it is not working.

I registered the proper DDLs but after register the dlls I am getting same error with different format

```
ST_API_NT4X4326.Helper_State::State_ViewStateBag [1.0.4] Line# 0 -->ST_API error '800a01ad'

Unhandled_Error_Routine:9/19/2017 6:46:11 AM on Thread:10984 -->ActiveX component can't create object

/TestPlan/include/CommonFunctions.asp, line 5
```

Someone Please help me.

Comment: Read this - [Error ASP 0177: 8007007e Server.CreateObject fails for COM DLL](//stackoverflow.com/a/35985827). If you have moved to another server, is it running the iOS in 64-bit or 32 Bit? This is very important when it comes to registering the COM DLL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error ASP 0177: 8007007e Server.CreateObject fails for COM DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976543/error-asp-0177-8007007e-server-createobject-fails-for-com-dll)