# ActiveX component can't create object "NIBLACK.ASPFTP"

Tags: vbscript, ftp, upload, activex, regsvr32

I had a problem when I executed my script. My script function is to upload a text file from my server to another server.

I have `set objFTP = createObject("NIBLACK.ASPFTP")` in my script, but when I run that script, I get the following error:

> ActiveX component can't create object "NIBLACK.ASPFTP".

For that problems, I've registered "aspftp.dll" and copied that file to "C:\Windows\System32" and "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" with `regsvr32`, but it didn't work at all.

My server is windows server 2012 R2 Standard.

Any suggestions why the object cannot be created?

Comment: You can't just copy the DLL into both the 32-bit and 64-bit system folder locations and hope for the best, that's just silly. For example trying to register a 32-bit DLL with the 64-bit `regsvr32.exe` will fail. First, establish what you have, 32-bit or 64-bit then open an elevated cmd prompt and use the correct version of `regsvr32.exe` to register the DLL. I wrote a [Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942) in another question that explains how to work through registering a DLL, check through that before posting *(some info is specific to IIS but most of it is relevant)*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error ASP 0177: 8007007e Server.CreateObject fails for COM DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976543/error-asp-0177-8007007e-server-createobject-fails-for-com-dll)