# Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object in VBA/VBS/WSH

Tags: vba, vbscript, activex, wsh

I know it has been asked so many times, but I've gone through dozens of pages, with no luck, since mine seems to be a OS/machine related problem rather then of a specific library.

Trying to manage ID3Tags, or in general, files extended properties, it's clear that with a Shell object you can only retrieve them, but can't edit, therefore the only way to do that is using an external DLL (es. CDDBControl, or DSOfile), I can't get them to work, although I apparently successfully installed them with regsvr32 (references are available i.e. in Excel macro dev env.

I tried many ways....using regsvr32 either under System32 or SysWOW64, trying to put the DLLs in different location....but nothing.

Statement raising the error:

```
Set id3 = CreateObject("CDDBControl.CddbID3Tag")
```

Please note that a call like

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

instead, gives no error at all.

Comment: SO is W7 Professional 64bit genuinely activated

Comment: Did you try adding the reference in the VBA IDE under Tools? The DLL is here usually `\Windows\System32\scrrun.dll`. Once added, you do early binding.

Comment: This also might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically

Comment: *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* is standard issue on every Windows box. What did you do with the type library and why are you trying to re-register it?

Comment: Wait, no error at all with `CreateObject(progId)`, so all is good then - what's the problem? Your question is quite unclear... can you show us the code that *doesn't* work? See [mcve].

Comment: Please show the code that raises the error instead of code that does not raise an error.

Comment: The code giving error is: 
Set id3 = CreateObject("CDDBControl.CddbID3Tag")  
As already stated above, the cddbcontrol.dll has been successfully registered via regsvr32 and it appears in the VBA references.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f2b43f4-1a06-45e5-b05f-e1a2040feb32/cddbcontrolcddbid3tag-runtime-error-429-activex-component-cant-create-object?forum=isvvba

Comment: [Worth reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942) in detail *(it applies to situation where you are registering COM for use with VBScript, JScript or VBA)*.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution....hope this could help someone else....
The only way I made it work is to follow the instructions given in the page:
[Setting MP3 ID Tags with CDDBControl.dll](http://reidablog.blogspot.com/2006/07/setting-mp3-id-tags-with.html)

Cheers.