# What does Simatic.Simatic.1" mean?

Tags: vbscript, plc, wincc

I have the following function in my VBScript which I do not know what the purpose of it is:

```
CreateObject("Simatic.Simatic.1")
```

What does the `Simatic.Simatic.1` mean?

Comment: It's the name of a COM class. That statement is supposed to create an instance of that class (i.e. an object).

Comment: It’s a pointer to where COM DLL registration is in the registry. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942) for a break-down of how it works and how to identify where the associated DLL is located.

Answer (score 2):

Simatic.Simatic.1 (Simatic 1.0 Type Library) is a COM Type Library DLL from Siemens. You can find more information about type libraries here:
[COM, DCOM, and Type Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/midl/com-dcom-and-type-libraries)

If you have Step7 installed on your computer you can find the library e.g. here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Siemens\Step7\S7BIN\
```

The name of the library is S7ABATCX.dll/S7ABATCX.TLB.

This library is the **STEP 7 command interface**.

Excerpt from the Siemens documentation:

> You can use the command interface to access STEP 7 functions that presently can be executed only by means of the interface for applications that you programmed yourself. The command interface is an OLE automation interface through which the selected objects and functions of STEP 7 can be addressed. This does not mean that you can implement any configuration tools with the command interface because, as an OLE automation interface, this interface does not provide the entire object model or the entire functionality of STEP 7, rather only a part of them.
>
> You can use the command interface with any OLE script languages with automation capability or programming languages such as Visual Basic Version 5 or higher, Visual C++, or Visual J++. The examples were tested with Visual Basic Version 6 ; however, in principle, they can also run with Version 5.
>
> The following functions are supported:
>
> ·  Creating and deleting objects
>   ·   Navigating through the object model
>   ·   Accessing selected attributes
>
> In addition, functions are provided that cover the most essential configuration scenarios. The use of this description for self-programmed access to STEP 7 objects and the use of STEP 7 functions is not connected to any obligation or guarantee of any kind. Siemens therefore assumes no responsibility based on the use of this description or parts thereof.

You can find examples and the documentation on the installation media of Step 7, e.g. 
STEP 7 V5.5 Professional 2010 SR3_Manuals\English\Command Interface.

If you are using “TIA Portal” you should use the [TIA Portal Openness interface](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/ww/en/view/108716692) instead.