# VBScript object property/method call?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am debugging a legacy classic asp site using VBScript. In the global.asa file, I found there are some code, I couldn't figure out where the method/property comes from. Wonder if anyone could point me out the direction, please?

```
Dim ArrayIndex, AllCityIDs, AllCityNames, EmployeeIDs, EmployeeNames, oEmp

    Set oCity = Server.CreateObject("EmployeeDB.City")
    Set colCities = oCity.List

    Set oEmp = Server.CreateObject("EmployeeDB.Employee")

    Redim CityEmployeeArray (colCities.Count - 1)

    ArrayIndex = 0
    ' for each City, let's build the Employee list for that city.
    for each oItem In colCities
        AllCityIDs = AllCityIDs & oItem.Index & " || "
        AllCityNames = AllCityNames & oItem.Value & " || "

        'response.Write("oItem.Index:")
        'response.Write(oItem.Index)

        Set colCityEmployees = oEmp.EmployeesByCity (oItem.Index)

        'response.Write("colCityEmployees:")
        'response.Write(colCityEmployees.Count)

        EmployeeIDs = vbNullString
        EmployeeNames = vbNullString

        for each oCityEmp in colCityEmployees
            EmployeeIDs = EmployeeIDs & oCityEmp.Index & " || "
            EmployeeNames = EmployeeNames & oCityEmp.Value & " || "
        next

        EmployeeIDs = RemoveEndDelimiter (EmployeeIDs, " || ")
        EmployeeNames = RemoveEndDelimiter (EmployeeNames, " || ")

        CityEmployeeArray(ArrayIndex) = Array(oItem.Index, Array(EmployeeIDs, EmployeeNames))

        ArrayIndex = ArrayIndex + 1
    next

    Set oCity = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am wondering for this line

```
Set colCityEmployees = oEmp.EmployeesByCity (oItem.Index)
```

Where does the EmployeesByCity property/method come from? And how it gets the value for colCityEmployees from the oItem.Index parameter?

I also get an error for line when run the page on local IIS

```
for each oCityEmp in colCityEmployees
```

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01c3'

Object not a collection

/LM/W3SVC/5/ROOT/PHONELISTADMIN/global.asa, line 80

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The `oEmp` object comes from a COM DLL that has been registered with the registry with a progid of `EmployeeDD.Employee`. From the looks of it the DLL is acting as a Data Access Layer *(see [Multitier Architecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture))* you may need to configure a connection before it returns the expected data.

Comment: [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942) about configuring and diagnosing registration issues with COM DLLs you may find useful.

Comment: Thank you. I have an connection somewhere on the top defined and registered the component in the registry. But wondering where is EmployeesByCity coming from? Is that something generated from Data Access Layer?

Comment: It's a method call from that registered COM DLL, so yes its coming from the DAL.

Comment: Thank you. So I guess for properties like Index and Value of Object item oItem, they are defined in the COM DLL, right? Is there anyway I can find out what properties/function/method without the COM DLL source code?

Comment: @XiaoHan you can use [OLE-COM Object Viewer](http://download.microsoft.com/download/win2000platform/oleview/1.00.0.1/NT5/EN-US/oleview_setup.exe) to view COM libraries.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin, Thanks. For some reason, the application couldn't load due to some dll problem. But I found that within Component Services, if I go to the component, under Interfaces, then keep expanding, under Methods, I can see the methods available for each component/class. The may be another way to find out what's inside the DLLs.