# Server.CreateObject Failed aspsessionservice IIS 10

Tags: .net, docker, session, iis

I'm fairly new to DevOps (originally networking/infrastructure!) and I'm currently trying to rebuild one of our demo ASP classic sites (with some .NET modules) into a docker container. I've struggled along and now hit an error I'm not sure how to fix. Any help from devs greatly appreciated.

Environment - IIS 10, 2016 docker image (.NET), MSSQL 2016.

When trying to load the main site I'm seeing the error:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' 

Server.CreateObject Failed 
C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\WEBSITE\params.asp, line ###
800401f3
```

The params file line it's complaining about:

```
Set Session = Server.CreateObject("AspSessionService.AspSession")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the issue using this very helpful walkthrough on another post.

It was the Homelidays session service DLL which needed registering.

Here’s the handy walkthrough:

[Error ASP 0177: 8007007e Server.CreateObject fails for COM DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976543/error-asp-0177-8007007e-server-createobject-fails-for-com-dll/35985827#35985827)