# location of executable invoked by wscript.createobject()

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I need to know how to locate the executable invoked by `wscript.createobject()`.

I inherited a mass of old code that I'm trying to untangle. A VBS file invokes a custom executable with this line:

```
Set TGen = wscript.createobject("VbTextGen.TextGen")
```

I would like to find that executable but have not been able to. I understand the argument is server.typename but that doesn't tell me much. I've looked in the directory containing the vbscript file, the path, and some system directories

`Set TGen = wscript.createobject("VbTextGen.TextGen")` is all I have to go on.

Hoping someone can tell me where to find this thing.

Comment: This answer should help - [Section: What If You Don't Know Where the DLL Is Located?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942).

Comment: Wow. Astonishing. Thank you very much. A small correction- the GUID, in my case, was in 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{my_guid_here}. The article said it would be found in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.

Comment: Glad I could help, if you found the question and/or answer useful consider [upvoting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error ASP 0177: 8007007e Server.CreateObject fails for COM DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976543/error-asp-0177-8007007e-server-createobject-fails-for-com-dll)

Comment: Thank you @rdgWarren, you are absolutely right. Must have missed that when I went through my example steps, will correct it now.