# Server Object Error 'ASP 0177 : 800aea5f Server.CreateObject Failed

Tags: web, iis, asp-classic

we have a web application that is migrated to another server. Now, when accessing the application in the IIS, It displays a **Server Object Error 'ASP 0177: 800aea5f Server.CreateObject Failed** error.

I've tried restarting the IIS but still displays the same error. I'm also not familiar with the IIS, DLL, registry. Hope someone can guide me to this

Answer (score 0):

You need to check some following things:

1)The name of the object you are trying to create was misspelled or is incorrect.

2)your DLL has proper permission or not.

3)is DLL is available at the place which you mention in code.
and please provide full error message which lines cause this error message.

For more information you could follow this link:
[Server Object Error 'ASP 0177:80040154' Server.CreateObject](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/175804/prb-server-object-error-asp-0177-80040154-server-createobject)

Comment: Good advice but a more detail checklist can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942).