# ASP Support form error: Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' Server.CreateObject Failed

Tags: com, asp-classic

My application works in classic ASP. I'm getting the following error in "support" page after clicking the submit button.

Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

```
    set Mailer=Server.CreateObject("SMTPsvg.Mailer")
```

I have limited knowledge about classic ASP. How to fix the issue?

Comment: The `CreateObject()` method is used to instantiate a COM object from an external DLL that is registered with COM via the Windows Registry. It uses what is own as the ProgId to identifier, in this case you should have a ProgId registered as "localhost" which seems a bit strange to me. You should [find this checklist helpful in identifying it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942).

Comment: This may be one of those cases where it's better to tell us what you're trying to accomplish, so that we might tell you how to accomplish it

Comment: @Lankymart have to fix it without updating the DLL. Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: @StephenR Have to send email using ASP classic. I have updated the question now with the specific code. Hope it gives you an idea.