# Permission Denied CreateObject("Excel.Application.16")

Tags: excel, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm working on a legacy web application written in classic asp on a Windows Server 2022. Excel 2016 is installed. This has been working fine on an older machine. This is a new instance of the site (on AWS).

Trying to open an uploaded Excel file and get the 'Permission Denied' and references the line;

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application.16")
```

I have granted IIS_IUSRS read, write and execute permission to the file directory and to the Office 16 folder.

Still getting errors.

Comment: Is Office 2016 installed for 32-Bit or 64 Bit?

Comment: You may find [this check list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942) helpful for diagnosing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\` of your system by using Registry Editor app.

There you can find out the name of the class installed.

Something like

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Application

or

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Application.16

or some other class name.

Use that name to create the object.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("<<NAME THAT YOU SEE IN REGISTRY FOR EXCEL>>")
```

Comment: That entirely depends if it’s the 32 or 64 bit version of Office 2016, as that will change where the classes are registered.

Comment: There’s a more comprehensive [check list guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942).