# ActiveX component can't create object: 'PCOMM.autECLPS' using IBM PCOMM 14.0 HACL Automation

Tags: vbscript, com, ibm-pcomm

Trying to programmatically automate IBM PCOMM v 14.0 using Host Access Class Library Automation Objects in VBScript through Visual Studio Code IDE:

```
Option Explicit
Dim autECLPSObj 
Dim autECLConnList
Dim autECLOIAObj

Dim PSText

Set autECLPSObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")
Set autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")
Set autECLOIAObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLOIA")

' Refresh must be called to get latest connection info
autECLConnList.Refresh
' Initialize the connection with the first in the list
autECLPSObj.SetConnectionByHandle (autECLConnList(1).Handle)
' Initialize the connection with Session Name
autECLOIAObj.SetConnectionByName ("A")

        autECLPSObj.SendKeys "PCOMM API’s are very Powerful", 3, 1
        'autECLPSObj.SendKeys “[Enter]”
        'PSText = GetText(1, 1, 10)
        'autECLPSObj.SetCursorPos 2, 1
        autECLOIAObj.WaitForInputReady (10000)
    Set autECLPSObj = Nothing
    Set autECLConnList = Nothing
    Set autECLOIAObj = Nothing
```

Getting the following error: **Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'PCOMM.autECLPS'**

The PCOMM [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSEQ5Y_14.0.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/pdf/host_accessV140.pdf) says Automation will work only using 64-bit version of MS Office.

My current installed versions are:

1. Office version is 'Microsoft 365 MSO 64-bit'
2. Windows OS: Windows 10 Enterprise (64-bit)
3. IBM Personal Communications (PCOMM) version 14.0

Clarification:

1. Is the above error due to bit incompatibility? Based on [product readme](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/personal-communications/14.0?topic=files-version-140#Introducing_64bit_PCOMM) file,I suppose the PCOMM 14.0 is 64 bit version
2. How do I determine whether it is 64-bit or 32-bit PCOMM installed?
3. I'm not clear whether the Office version and Windows OS should be downgraded to 32 bit version?

Comment: Recommend going through [this checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942) to help diagnose how / where the COM DLL is registered.

Comment: The documentation you link to says it 32 bit not 64 bit. Therefore use a 32 bit client or force the dll to be loaded in dllhost.exe. Exe files don't care about bitness. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/dllsurrogate. You tagged this VBScript - there are 32 bit vbscript in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error ASP 0177: 8007007e CreateObject fails for COM DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976543/error-asp-0177-8007007e-createobject-fails-for-com-dll)

Comment: @user692942 your answer was highly informative as I got know the indepth details on dll / registry works. In this case I verified the dll were indeed registered properly

Comment: @user18521918 I thought this was a 64 bit application then realized its 32-bit. When I ran the code again in 32 bit vbscript , it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

PCOMM also should be 64bit version. you can find it  by clicking Help > About Personal Communications (on the Menu). (you need to save the macro file on C drive.) Both office and PCOMM bit versions should be same.