# Create Object Chilkat Failing on Win Server 2022

Tags: iis, vbscript, com, asp-classic, chilkat

I have installed the Chilkat ActiveX software and all components seem to be registered. However, I am getting the following error at this line of code:

```
set http = Server.CreateObject("Chilkat_9_5_0.Http")
```

Error:

> error '80040154'

We have upgraded from Win Server 2008 r2 to Win Server 2022 DC and I can't seem to get the object to be created.

Any help on this one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error ASP 0177: 8007007e CreateObject fails for COM DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976543/error-asp-0177-8007007e-createobject-fails-for-com-dll). Use the check list to resolve the "Class not registered" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue. I needed to install the 32bit version not the 64bit.

Comment: I don't know about this particular suite, but you can use 64 bit COM components with classic ASP.  It's either/or, so you need to set Enable 32 bit to false in the app pool.  Most components are available in 32 or 64 bit versions, the most notable exception is the JET (.mdb Access) database driver - which is 32 bit only.

Comment: Thanks @John. I need the 32 bit enabled in the app pool due to other activex components being used with this website.