# About creating PDF

Tags: asp-classic, activexobject

In classic Asp, I have installed ABCpdf8.dll for creating PDF, but I am getting an error.

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'.
ActiveX component can't create object.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The two most likely possibilities are that you haven't actually registered ABCpdf.dll on your server, or that the IUSR account associated with your website doesn't have read/execute permission on ABCpdf.dll

Your error message suggests that you are using CreateObject() rather than Server.CreateObject() - which would give you a different message - "Server.CreateObject Failed".  Take a look at this question about another third party component - the issues are the same.

[Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' Server.CreateObject Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945392/server-object-error-asp-0177-800401f3-server-createobject-failed)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the component ABCpdf8, you can use an PHP lib (as mpdf) for create the PDF, group the informations in an variable HTML and send to PHP page with MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.