# Having trouble with a image uploader on an ASP website

Tags: error-log

I have an image uploader built into a site for properties and it was working fine and now whenever i use the image uploader it gives me a 500 internal server error message.

My error log looks like this, does anyone know how to make sense of what its telling me?

ERROR LOG FILE - 
https://pastebin.com/QtenvubM

CODE FOR UPLOADER:

```
  <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<!--#include virtual="/connection_includes/prop_search_conn_str.asp" -->
<%

Fkey = request.QueryString("Fkey")
property_ID = request.QueryString("property_ID")

uploadpath = "/palm_group/property_images/prop_no_" & property_ID

'------------------------------------------------------------

Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fs.FolderExists(server.MapPath(uploadpath)) = true Then
      folder_exists = "yes"
Else
      folder_exists = "no"
End If

'response.write uploadpath
'response.write folder_exists
'response.write server.MapPath(uploadpath)

'------------------------------------------------------------

if folder_exists = "no" then

        fs.createfolder(server.MapPath(uploadpath))

end if

'-------------------------------------------------------------

Sub ImageUpload()
Server.ScriptTimeout = 555 '[Two Minute Timeout (this will allow upto 2 minutes of activity before ending)]
Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
Count = Upload.Save(Server.MapPath(uploadpath))

        For Each File in Upload.Files
                LOCAL_LOC = File.Path
                REMOTE_LOC = RootDir & replace(file.path, Server.mappath(uploadpath) + "\", "")
                FILE_SIZE = File.Size
                session("file") = File.filename
        Next

Set Upload = Nothing
End Sub

'-------------------------------------------------------------
Call ImageUpload()
'-------------------------------------------------------------
if session("file") = "" then
        set fname=nothing
        set fs=nothing
        response.redirect "/CMS_ADMIN_FILES/edit_property.asp?error=nofile&unique_ID=" & property_ID & "&Fkey=" & Fkey
end if
'-------------------------------------------------------------


file_extension = lcase(right(session("file"),4))
file_is_image = "false"

if file_extension = "jpeg" then file_extension = ".jpg"

        if file_extension = ".jpg" then file_is_image = "true"
        if file_extension = ".png" then file_is_image = "true"
        if file_extension = ".gif" then file_is_image = "true"

if file_is_image <> "true" then

        If fs.FileExists(server.MapPath(uploadpath & "\" & session("file"))) = true Then
                fs.DeleteFile(server.MapPath(uploadpath & "\" & session("file")))
        end if

        set fname=nothing
        set fs=nothing

        response.redirect "/CMS_ADMIN_FILES/edit_property.asp?error=notimage&unique_ID=" & property_ID & "&Fkey=" & Fkey

else

'       response.write file_extension
'       response.write "<br>"
'       response.write server.MapPath(uploadpath & "\" & session("file"))

if instr(session("file"),",") then response.Redirect "/CMS_ADMIN_FILES/edit_property.asp?error=illegalchar&unique_ID=" & property_ID & "&Fkey=" & Fkey

old_file = server.MapPath(uploadpath & "\" & session("file"))

file_counter = 1
stop_this_loop = "go"
session.Contents.Remove("file")

        do while stop_this_loop = "go"

                        if file_counter < 10 then
                                new_file = "0" & file_counter & file_extension
                        else
                                new_file = file_counter & file_extension
                        end if
        response.write "<br>" & new_file

                If fs.FileExists(server.MapPath(uploadpath & "\" & new_file)) = true Then

                        file_counter = file_counter + 1

                else

                        stop_this_loop = "stop"

                end if

                        if file_counter < 10 then
                                new_file = "0" & file_counter & file_extension
                        else
                                new_file = file_counter & file_extension
                        end if

        loop

                        fs.CopyFile old_file,server.MapPath(uploadpath & "\" & new_file)
                        fs.DeleteFile(old_file)

end if

set fname=nothing
set fs=nothing


' GET THE LAST LARGEST IMAGE ORDER NUMBER AND ADD ONE TO IT

Set order_images = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
order_images.ActiveConnection = CONN_property_search_images
order_images.Source = "SELECT TOP 1 img_order FROM property_images WHERE img_property_ID='" & session("ID") & "' ORDER BY img_order DESC"
order_images.CursorType = 0
order_images.CursorLocation = 2
order_images.LockType = 2
order_images.Open()

        if order_images.eof then
                new_order_number = 1
        else
                new_order_number = order_images("img_order") + 1
        end if

order_images.close
set order_images = nothing

' NOW STICK IT IN THE DATABASE AND HAVE DONE WITH IT


        Set DBCmd_content = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        DBCmd_content.ActiveConnection = CONN_property_search_images
        DBCmd_content.CommandText = "INSERT INTO property_images(img_decription,img_property_ID,img_url,img_order) VALUES('','" & property_ID & "','" & uploadpath & "/" & new_file & "','" & new_order_number & "')"
        DBCmd_content.Execute
        DBCmd_content.ActiveConnection.Close

        response.Redirect "/CMS_ADMIN_FILES/edit_property.asp?action=addok&unique_ID=" & property_ID & "&Fkey=" & Fkey

%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the registration of the Persits Upload DLL. See here:

[Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' Server.CreateObject Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945392/server-object-error-asp-0177-800401f3-server-createobject-failed)